# jquery removeClass seems not to work, how to?

Tags: jquery, html, css, removeclass

i have a simple example of using `removeClass` but it doesnt seem to work properly. Im not sure why i cant see the problem

html

```
<ul id="alljobs" class="hide">123</ul>
<ul id="jobs" class="hide">123</ul>
```

css

```
.hide{color:red;}
```

js

```
var x=1;

if (x ==1 ){
$('#jobs').removeClass('.hide');
}
```

in this case one ul text color should be black, but it isn't

any ideas?

here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/rdrNc/)

thanks

Comment: No need for the dot in `removeClass('**.**hide')`, because jQuery already knows you want a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#jobs').removeClass('hide');
```

You need to take out the period in your class name.  The period is used in a selector for noting that the string to follow is a class name.  But in the `removeClass()` function, the parameter is simply a string that is the class' name.

The fixed jQuery code, in total, would be this:

```
var x=1; 

if (x ==1 ){ 
$('#jobs').removeClass('hide'); 
}
```

Comment: @Patrioticcow Ha, honest mistake.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dot(`.`) from class name.

```
$('#jobs').removeClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 2):

remote the . from your class name, it's not really part of the class name when using jquery.